# All the div content changing when clicking only one div in the foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery

I am displaying content using php foreach loop as,

```
<?php
foreach($result as $value)
{
?>
<div class="content">
<?=$value['title']?>
</div>
<?php

}
?>
```

I am applying jquery clck event to change the content of particular div in the above foreach loop using jquery as

```
$(function()
{
   $('.content').click(function()
   {
       $(this).html('welcome to app');
   });
});
```

All the div's content are changing, can anyone tell me how to chnage the only particular div content when click on it.

Comment: Depends on how you wrote you code

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Use unique "id" instead of "class" name

Comment: depends what he needs ... he can declare a variable and increment it ... and a lot of if`s statements :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your question and it seems to be working fine at my PC. I would appreciate if you can share browser information  for further investigation. Meanwhile, I am sharing the code which is working perfectly.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
     <head>
      <title> New Document </title>
      <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus">
      <meta name="Author" content="">
      <meta name="Keywords" content="">
      <meta name="Description" content="">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>

     <body>
      <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
      <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
     </body>
     <script>
     $(function()
     {
        $('.content').click(function() {
            $(this).html('Hello');
        })
     });
    </script>
    </html>
```